# Case insensitive username checking?

Tags: php

I am currently making a registration system and when checking the username to see if it's taken, it throws an error only if the username is EXACTLY like the one in the database. What i'm saying, is:

someone called SomeGuy makes an account

someone else tries making an account called SomeGuy

gets error, so he tries someGuy (different cases)

no error occurs

Here is my code!:

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            $randomNums = rand(1, 400);
            $suggestedName = strtolower($username) . $randomNums;
            $errorMsg = "This username is already taken! How about you try this? ".$suggestedName;
            $error = true;
        }
```

Comment: It's in this paste. https://pastebin.com/tBCLR7Dp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select case insensitive using mysql, php and pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850683/select-case-insensitive-using-mysql-php-and-pdo)

Comment: it doesn't work, i don't know how to do it with the WHERE clause. maybe some code?